# How to use the Python Sentry SDK (raven-python) with a HTTP proxy

Tags: python, http-proxy, sentry

I have a webapp which uses the raven-python SDK for Sentry for error reporting. I want outbound requests of that SDK to go through a HTTP proxy.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi, I work at sentry. Gunicorn doesn't have anything to do with outbound requests or any I/O other than incoming requests. I don't understand what you mean with the pipeline in your .ini file. Are you trying to funnel raven traffic through a HTTP proxy?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer that's correct, all of Raven's outbound traffic has to go through an HTTP proxy. I included details about Gunicorn here because it has to ingest a `.ini` file with some Pyramid application config in it, and was hoping that another config entry in this file would allow the use of an outbound proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternative [Transport such as the requests one](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/transports/#requests). With the requests transport you can use environment variables to set the proxy: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Example:

```
from raven.transport.threaded_requests import ThreadedRequestsHTTPTransport

Client('...', transport=ThreadedRequestsHTTPTransport)
```

And in your environment, set `HTTPS_PROXY=https://localhost:9090` or something like that.

Comment: As a side note, we have a new Python SDK currently in alpha that supports these environment variables out of the box: https://forum.sentry.io/t/new-python-sdk-feedback-wanted/4366

Comment: Thanks, Markus! I was exploring this yesterday after getting it as a suggestion on the Sentry forums. I'll give it a shot later today.